# how to use method max PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to find information from two tables -  total goals per season for each team. That's how I did it:

```
SELECT Team, sum(G) as "Total Goals"
From Stats, HockeyPlayer
Where HockeyPlayer.Player_ID = Stats.Player_ID
group by Team;
```

Now, I need to find what team score the most goals. How to use method max here?
Thank you

Comment: no need for max. `order by "total goals" desc limit 1`, basically. unless you took steps, using `max("total goals")` would disassociate the max goal from the team(s) that actually scored it.

Comment: thank you. I did it with `order by / limit` as well. but I am asked to do it with a `max` function (e.g. instead of `order by/limit`).

Comment: Make you query a sub-query of the one that uses `MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

This query will help you.

```
SELECT 
  *, MAX(goals) AS m_goals 
FROM (
  SELECT Team, sum(G) as goals
  From Stats, HockeyPlayer
  Where HockeyPlayer.Player_ID = Stats.Player_ID
  group by Team
  ) as t
WHERE 
    goals=m_goals
```

Try to use this query, instead of previous.

Comment: ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
LINE 11:     goals=max(goals);
                   ^

Comment: SELECT *, max(goals) as m_goals FROM (...) as t WHERE goals = m_goals, try to update select and where values.